# For Armature linking, is there a maximum number of faces allowed?

Tags: rigging, armature

I've created an armature for a character, but when I run CTRL-P-I to set the parent with automatic weights, my computer chugs for a bit but when it's done and I use pose-mode, the armature doesn't affect the mesh. And if I look at the weights, they're all the darkest blue.

If I decimate the mesh before parenting the armature, it worked. Is there a max-mesh complexity for which this will work? If so, is it a fixed number or computer-dependent?

EDIT: Ok. I lied, I do get an error, but not in the console, but where I said there wasn't one, the notification area at the top:

```
Bone Heat Weighting: Failed to find a solution for one or more bones.
```

EDIT: FYI, the mesh starts with about 1/2 Million Faces, and it successfully rigs when I get to about 60,000.

Comment: This sounds weird. Are there any error message in the console? Can you upload your blend file?

Comment: There are no error messages. I will look into how to upload here, I've never done that before. (I could link to a cloud drive right away, but I'm unsure of the etiquette on that.)

Comment: I should add that I've tried all the tips I've found, which involve removing doubles, making normals consistent, and other cleanup mesh operations.

Comment: I should say there were no errors that showed in the notification area at the top, but I didn't check the console. I will do so.